# SQL to arrange calculate times as per given conditions

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I've the following schema and the data:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[EntryExitLogs]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntryExitLogs](
    [DeviceLogId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LogDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Direction] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EntryExitLogs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeCode] ASC,
    [LogDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EntryExitLogs]([DeviceLogId],[EmployeeCode],[LogDate],[Direction]) VALUES('435859','30032','2014-01-21 07:04:41','in');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EntryExitLogs]([DeviceLogId],[EmployeeCode],[LogDate],[Direction]) VALUES('438019','30032','2014-01-21 08:59:09','out');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EntryExitLogs]([DeviceLogId],[EmployeeCode],[LogDate],[Direction]) VALUES('441564','30032','2014-01-21 16:57:35','in');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EntryExitLogs]([DeviceLogId],[EmployeeCode],[LogDate],[Direction]) VALUES('441263','30032','2014-01-21 19:09:19','out');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EntryExitLogs]([DeviceLogId],[EmployeeCode],[LogDate],[Direction]) VALUES('441264','30032','2014-01-21 19:10:20','in');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EntryExitLogs]([DeviceLogId],[EmployeeCode],[LogDate],[Direction]) VALUES('439928','34035','2014-01-21 08:29:59','in');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EntryExitLogs]([DeviceLogId],[EmployeeCode],[LogDate],[Direction]) VALUES('437962','34035','2014-01-21 08:30:12','in');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EntryExitLogs]([DeviceLogId],[EmployeeCode],[LogDate],[Direction]) VALUES('437992','34035','2014-01-21 08:47:33','out');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EntryExitLogs]([DeviceLogId],[EmployeeCode],[LogDate],[Direction]) VALUES('440203','34035','2014-01-21 13:38:56','out');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EntryExitLogs]([DeviceLogId],[EmployeeCode],[LogDate],[Direction]) VALUES('442858','34035','2014-01-21 16:34:08','in');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EntryExitLogs]([DeviceLogId],[EmployeeCode],[LogDate],[Direction]) VALUES('442860','34035','2014-01-21 16:35:11','out');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EntryExitLogs]([DeviceLogId],[EmployeeCode],[LogDate],[Direction]) VALUES('441283','34035','2014-01-21 19:16:58','out');
```

I've written SQL to calculate In and out times like this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
                 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                            PARTITION BY lt.EmployeeCode ORDER BY lt.EmployeeCode,
                            lt.LogDate
                        )              AS RowNo,
                        lt.DeviceLogId,
                        lt.EmployeeCode,
                        lt.LogDate,
                        lt.Direction
                 FROM   EntryExitLogs     lt
             )
SELECT i.EmployeeCode,
       i.LogDate AS InTime,
       (
           SELECT MIN(o.LogDate)
           FROM   cte AS o
           WHERE  o.EmployeeCode = i.EmployeeCode
                  AND o.RowNo = (i.RowNo + 1)
                  AND o.Direction = 'out'
       )    AS OutTime
FROM   cte  AS i
WHERE  i.Direction = 'in'
ORDER BY i.EmployeeCode, i.LogDate
```

I'm getting the output (but not as desired by me), but I expect the output in the following manner (comments are given for more information against each row):

```
EmployeeCode InTime             OutTime                 Comments
30032   21-Jan-2014 07:04:41    21-Jan-2014 08:59:09    
30032   21-Jan-2014 16:57:35    21-Jan-2014 19:09:19    
30032   21-Jan-2014 19:10:20    NULL                    If no OUT is specified for the last IN then it should be NULL
34035   21-Jan-2014 08:29:59    21-Jan-2014 13:38:56    Earliest IN and Latest OUT to be taken in case of multiple IN & OUT
34035   21-Jan-2014 16:34:08    21-Jan-2014 19:16:58    Earliest IN and Latest OUT to be taken in case of multiple IN & OUT
```

Please find the schema for this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74a8b3/1)

Kindly help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
;WITH TrueOut AS --select only the latest "out" in between two "ins"
(
SELECT *
FROM EntryExitLogs a 
WHERE direction='out'
AND 
ISNULL((SELECT MIN(LogDate) FROM EntryExitLogs b 
WHERE a.EmployeeCode=b.Employeecode
AND b.direction='out'
AND b.LogDate>a.LogDate),'9999-12-31')
>=
ISNULL((SELECT MIN(LogDate) FROM EntryExitLogs b 
WHERE a.EmployeeCode=b.Employeecode
AND b.direction='in'
AND b.LogDate>a.LogDate),'9999-12-31')
),
TrueIn AS --select only the earlies "in" in between two "outs"
(
SELECT *
FROM EntryExitLogs a 
WHERE direction='in'
AND 
ISNULL((SELECT MAX(LogDate) FROM EntryExitLogs b 
WHERE a.EmployeeCode=b.Employeecode
AND b.direction='out'
AND b.LogDate<a.LogDate),'1900-01-01')
>=
ISNULL((SELECT MAX(LogDate) FROM EntryExitLogs b 
WHERE a.EmployeeCode=b.Employeecode
AND b.direction='in'
AND b.LogDate<a.LogDate),'1900-01-01')
)
-- For every in select the next out
SELECT a.EmployeeCode, a.LogDate InTime, 
(SELECT MIN(LogDate) 
FROM TrueOut b
WHERE a.EmployeeCode=b.EmployeeCode
AND a.LogDate<b.LogDate) OutTIme
FROM TrueIn a
```

Comment: There is no criteria as such, which is not shown in this example. I need earliest in and latest out for adjacent IN - OUT pair.

Comment: @Nagesh I've edited the answer is basically the same concept as originally but with a prior clearing of consecutive in/out times.

Comment: Dear @Jayvee thanks for your time. Yes, your solution is as per my requirement. I'll test this (for performance also) and will let you know if there are issues. Again thanks for your effort.